# Facebook Application Approval

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I'm developing a Facebook application.

It can be seen here:

http://apps.facebook.com/tangram-girbaud/

When the user has to aprove the application, this comes to the screen:

[image]

A Facebook logo inside the canvas, and the user does not click the logo.

If you click that logo Facebook sends you to the aproval window.

Is there any way to override this view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to redirect using the below script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.top.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id=196403870434233&display=page&next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pilatosapp.com%2Ftangram-girbaud%2F&response_type=code&fbconnect=1&perms=publish_stream%2Cuser_about_me%2Cuser_birthday";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

from frame info, address of frame is:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id=196403870434233&display=page&next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pilatosapp.com%2Ftangram-girbaud%2F&response_type=code&fbconnect=1&perms=publish_stream%2Cuser_about_me%2Cuser_birthday

As you somehow frame facebook.com, it doesn't show the content instead facebook logo.

you may inspect further why permission dialog opens not at `window.top`